# how do you assign a Jira Issue-Type-Questn under a user story in greenhopper?

Tags: dependencies, jira, task, greenhopper

I have been using JIRA and Greenhopper to support our Scrum Methodology. Since the User story is the requirement, how then will I be able to track Issue Type "Questions" and link it to a User Story in Greenhopper so that it also appears under the Task Board?  I wanted this to happen so that any dependency for the User Story will be addressed through the questions instead of putting comments in the User story where it is sometimes missed out and not addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add the questions as a sub-task to the story. That way you can track them in the Sprint easily.